# What does CDM mean?

Tags: terminology, ez-pz-rpg

What does CDM mean? I've got it as buff on my equipment, but there is no reference as far as I know in the game to it. There is nothing in the list on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDM) that fits either (assuming I can't increase the Cold Dark Matter).

[image: Screenshot of the game]

Comment: i assume it could be mean Critical DaMage. But it would be nice if someone find a valid source to a valid answer

Comment: @Serverfrog Well, it does fit. And there is no other relic that increases the critical damage, while it is a stat that can be increased in other rpgs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [here on Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1onPtNhNd5YLjUUeIUpQ9wkHdQAgEsXhW2afDrusBmPs/edit) a big text where stand many things about the game. Another Source is [this](http://forum.r2games.com/showthread.php?165493-Relic-Effects-Details-CDM-PRES-RED-MRES-RED-ABSORB&s=0c6a8f6b459c79bbf9ee67c08672e9c1) which is a thread on the official Forum.

And I found what CDM is.

CDM is Critical Damage according the Following list i found on this guide

```
Gold relics (advance crafted)
Helmet:  = +7% P.RES
Ring:     = M.RED +7
Belt:      = +10% RSL
Boots:    = 8% Dodge
Gloves:  =  10% crit
Amulet  =  7% M.RES
Chest    =  8% armor
Pants    =  P.RES red 7
Weapon =  3% dmg
Offhand= 8% hit


Blue Relics (smelted/found)
Helmet:  = +0.2% hp regen a round in combat
Ring:     = +10% more gold
Belt:      = +5% hp
Boots:    = +5% xp
Gloves:  =  7% Critical damage CDM
Amulet  =  3% drop rate
Chest    =  2% CC (crowd control aka stuns/freeze so on)
Pants    = 2% attacker damage return
Weapon =  2% absorb (life steal)
Offhand= +8 true damage
```